# How to add avatar to authors list?

Tags: author, list, avatar, gravatar, list-authors

I have code that shows authors list:

```
<?php wp_list_authors( 'exclude_admin=0&optioncount=1' ); ?>
```

It works fine, with number of posts per author and author page link

https://images2.imgbox.com/52/54/WuEWKIn1_o.jpg

Now I want to add avatars to this code.

https://images2.imgbox.com/35/47/AN5XGkJK_o.jpg

( No plugins )

Thanks in advance !

---

I found this code, but Avatar and name are not linked. They are not linked to author page and number of posts are missing.
Also solution, It's not necessary for Avatar to be linked, but author name and instead Avatar custom image.

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users();
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    /* Here passing user email and avater size */
    echo get_avatar( $user->user_email , 96 );
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span>';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Hello, as per https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/, there's nothing in this function which seems to add the Avatar. Do you use a third party plugin to manage Avatar instead of native Gravatar ?

Comment: @Sébastien Serre

As I can see, the client is using the PublishPress Authors plugin but I doubt it's from the plugin options, It might have yust recall this part of the code.

Мaybe another php code solution for my question.

Comment: Client already have bunch of other plugins, so he needs just some PHP Snippet,

Maybe some new PHP code, it doesn’t have to be based on above code.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you check the PublishPress documentation: https://publishpress.com/knowledge-base/using-data-in-custom-layouts/

Comment: @Tony Djukic

I didn't until your suggestion, but that's plugin, I can't find what I want
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that PublishPress Authors may have it's own unique way of storing the author avatars/images, so anything anyone else puts up is going to be guesswork unless they've worked with PublishPress authors.  I recently put together a 'user profile picture' feature for a site that has thousands of members, but my code won't be of much use because I'm recording the images and storing them in a completely custom manner.  Sorry.